# Jquery Form-Plugin doesn't get Submit - Basic understanding

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, jquery-forms-plugin

I know there are several threads about this topic but I couldn't find one to fit my needs.

I'm simply trying to sand an form asynchronous using the jQueryFormPlugin.

I've got this basic form in index.php

```
<form id="test_form" action="http://127.0.0.1/MwebCms/index.php?admin=1&p=navigation&add=1" method="POST">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="title"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Speichern" name="submit"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Now after including Jquery and the Jquery form plugin I added this in my JavaScript file:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#test_form').ajaxForm(function() { 
            alert("test"); 
        }); 
    });
```

Now that's all fine and dandy, but if I now check in index.php for:

```
echo $_POST["title"];
```

It will never be set.

What am I doing wrong or is my basic understanding of the jqueryFormPlugin completely wrong at all?

Source: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started

Comment: Try to `print_r($_POST);` if you dont get anything check your browser console.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but sadly the browser-console-errorlog is empty, and so is the $_POST variable. And the alert("test") will be executed by the way.

Comment: It might be possible you are posting on wrong url.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the problem either :(
I'm generating the action dynamically using php: $link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

Comment: You made typo here in closing your `</form>`.

Comment: Sorry this seems to be a typo I only made here somehow. In my code it's correct.

Comment: I think you need to place it on click event of your submit button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78687/discussion-between-indrasinh-bihola-and-juggernaut).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake I made:

The $_POST was sent alright, but it wasn't displayed. After changing the jquery to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('form').ajaxForm(function(data) { 
    $("body").html(data);
});
});
```

It all worked properly.